# Domain registrar, DNS hosting, Web hosting A little confusion

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, nameserver, domain-registrar

I've .com domain and a php webhosting. I can easily manage to setup nameserver in registrar and hosting and connected my domain to my host. But I cant understand what the dns hosting part do. I've googled but couldn't find a easy-to-understand guide.

As per my understanding, request->registrar->hostingNS->index.php

And if it was with dns hosting means, request->registrar->dnsHostingNS->hostingNS->index.php

Am I right? Anyone can give some detailed and easy description?

Answer (score 2):

> I've googled but couldn't find a easy-to-understand guide

[Domain Name System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) in Wikipedia have nice pictures for easy explanation

> As per my understanding, request->registrar->hostingNS->index.php

Slightly wrong. Process of getting content from any resource, referenced by name, include 2 stage
- DNS stage, were client stage when the client knows which IP it will need to connect
- Connection stage, were requested work performed

registrar do nothing in this everyday's job - it's main task is only register (over "glue records") NSes of domain in Up-level DNS-zones

Fixed and simplified workflow will be something as

- client request URL (name)
- DNS-servers over hierarchical tree (up and down) will find DNS-servers, which have information about requested hostname (*DNS-hoster from question*) from URL and return IP (IPs) as response
- To this IP client will send request for resource. Server (webserver in our case) process request and **if** requested resource is known to him and exist - return data to client

As you can see only one authoritative DNS (for zone) used, if web-hosting separated from DNS-hosting, NSes of webhoster will be untouched

HTH

Comment: Well, one more info needed. How to I add my server's IP since it's not dedicated IP? A normal ping will reveal primary and secondary ns ip. Will it work effectively?

Comment: "server IP" is web-server or DNS-server?

Comment: I mean, I'm using shared server to host my files. So if I add the Name server of host, it just redirects default page of server, not to my host file. How can I do that, since there is no option to add name server in dns hosting but only IPV4  address?

Comment: Shared **web** hosting still have (some) IP for all hosted sites. You have to ask question about IP (or known name) to support and add to zone IN A or IN CNAME record (if I understood you correctly now)